# I am working in react js and I want to make this html code responsive to view on mobiles

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working in React js and wrote a code that is having two columns one is a login form and other is image now when I do inspect element and check whether is it responsive or not whether the view is perfect for mobile but what I found is  if I shrink the page login form goes out of page the image is half visible now I want to make it responsive that it can be viewed on mobiles

```
 <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div class="col-md-5" style={{paddingTop: '3%'}}>
    
            <div className="continer">
              <form method="post" className="form" id="form">
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="username">Employee ID</label>
                  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Employee ID" className="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" className="form-control" />
                </div>
                <a href>Forgot Password?</a>
                {/* <a style={{float: 'right'}} href="#">Sign Up</a> */}
                <button className="btn btn-danger mt-4" type="submit">Login</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div  class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2" style={{width: '100%', height: 'auto', objectFit: 'contain'}}>
            <img src="../img/Cap1.PNG" alt="Image" width={680} height={690} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're using bootstrap. First of all, what you want is to replace the `col-md-..` css class with `col-sm-..` or even `col-..`. See [boostrap grid documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) for the grid options which come with it.

The other issue why your image is not responsive is that you give it static `width` and `height` pixels, and the styling rules you apply on the parent div class will be overriden. You can fix that by applying the styling to the
`<img />` itself and remove the `width={680} height={690}`.

I have created a solution here: [stackblitz solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9887cv?file=src/App.js).